# selling ISO on AWS marketplace

Tags: aws-marketplace

Is it possible to sell ISO in aws marketplace? I was searching and so far I only found that it is possible to sell AMI, and I`m wondering if it is possible to sell iso directly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not list ISO but only AMI or Container image. Learn more about what you can list at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/user-guide-for-sellers.html